# Getting 'root records' from self-referencing table

Tags: sql, sql-server, hierarchical-data, recursive-query

I have a self-referencing table: there's an ID and a PARENTID column that allows the records to be ordered into a hierarchical structure (let's call them record hierarchies).

There's also a query (let's call it 'Query A') that returns a list of records from this table. Some of the returned records are 'root records' (PARENTID = NULL), while some are non-root records (PARENTID != NULL). Note that 'Query A' can return multiple records that belong to the same record hierarchy.

What I need to accomplish in the most efficient way (efficiency is important but not paramount) is to get the root records for all records returned by 'Query A' so that non-root records in 'Query A' are searched for their root records.

Comment: What is that query? a stored procedure? a view? just plain sql?

Comment: Zoher: just a plain SQL query.

Comment: Can you post the query?

Comment: It would help to understand the question and validate any proposed solution if you included in your question a sample data for your table, a sample of what your query A returns and what result you expect from the final query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of possible solutions:

```
declare @TableA table
(
  ID int,
  ParentID int NULL,
  Name varchar(100)
)

insert into @TableA(ID, ParentID, Name)
values
(1, NULL, 'root 1'),
(2, NULL, 'root 2'),
(3, 2, 'node 3->2'),
(4, 1, 'node 4->1'),
(5, 4, 'node 5->4->1'),
(6, 3, 'node 6->3->2'),
(7, 4, 'node 7->4->1'),
(8, 7, 'node 8->7->4->1')


;with QueryA as 
(
  /* your query could be here */
  select t.ID, t.Name
  from @TableA t
  where t.ID in (1, 3, 8)
),
Tree as
(
  select t.ID, t.ParentID, t.Name,
    case when t.ParentID is NULL then t.ID end as RootID
  from @TableA t
  /* starting from rows we have in QueryA */
  where t.ID in (select q.ID from QueryA q)

  union all

  select tt.ID, t.ParentID, t.Name,
    case when t.ParentID is NULL then t.ID end as RootID
  from @TableA t
  /* recursion to parents */
  inner join Tree tt on tt.ParentID = t.ID
)
select q.ID, q.Name, t.Name as RootName
from QueryA q
inner join Tree t on t.ID = q.ID and t.RootID is not NULL
order by 1, 2
```

Also you may start from building a tree without linking to QueryA (for whole table). Will look a bit simpler. In this case you'll refer QueryA in final statement only.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to retrieve `Root` Item of each item then you can use the following approach :

```
select t1.*,(case when t1.PARENTID is null then t1.ID else t1.PARENTID end ) Id_Root , 0 IsTraced into #tmp
from TableName t1 
left outer join TableName t2 on t1.ID=t1.PARENTID
order by t1.PARENTID

while exists(select TOP 1 * , (select PARENTID  from #tmp where ID=t1.PARENTID) Id_GrandParent from #tmp t1 where IsTraced=0 order by PARENTID desc )
begin
        Declare @CurrentID as uniqueIdentifier
        set @CurrentID = (select TOP 1 ID from #tmp t1 where IsTraced=0 order by PARENTID desc )
        Declare @CurrentParentID as uniqueIdentifier
        set @CurrentParentID = (select TOP 1 PARENTID from #tmp t1 where IsTraced=0 order by PARENTID desc )
        Declare @CurrentGrandParentID as uniqueidentifier
        set @CurrentGrandParentID=(select PARENTID from #tmp where ID=@CurrentParentID)

        if(@CurrentGrandParentID is null)
        begin
            update #tmp set IsTraced=1 where ID=@CurrentID
        end
        else
        begin
            update #tmp set PARENTID= @CurrentGrandParentID, Id_Root=@CurrentGrandParentID  where ID=@CurrentID
        end
end

select ID,Id_Root
from #tmp 
order by PARENTID
```

as you can see after the while loop you can retrieve `ID` and `Id_Root` of each element from the `Temp Table #tmp`

Comment: I do not see how this answer fulfills the requirement for getting only the specific root records. These queries will select all of them.

Comment: @Daniel I edited my answer and added a way you can retrieve all items and their root item in the table

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into it.

Answer (score 0):

Is this a trick question? Firstly, each record only has 1 parent. And only the root records have a null parent value. Therefore, you don't have to do anything complicated to get just the root records.

```
Select * from QueryA where PARENTID is null
```

gets you all the root records after an *truly exhaustive searc*h of all the records by the query engine! All the other records, where PARENTID is not null, are not root records, they are child records by definition.

Comment: Please read the question again. Filtering for NULL is SQL 101 stuff. I wouldn't be asking the question if that was the case.

Comment: Clearly I didn't understand your question. I have developed a project management system that uses a self-referencing dataset, so I will be able to  answer your question if I understood what you are asking. What it comes down to is: how many records have PARENTID is null? Is it just 1 or > 1?